# How does distributed architecture work for serving out dynamic and static content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, distributed-computing, amazon-elb

Here is my scenario.

I have a map tiling server creating thousands of mapping tiles at different zoom levels. Currently this is run on one EC2 instance. I would like to stick with AWS.

Current workflow - 
A request for a tile comes in, nginx checks if that tile exists in a cache. If the tile exists, it serves it out. If it doesn't exist, it passes the request onto a tile creation script which both serves the newly created tile to the user and caches it for future use. This is starting to bog down when lots of tiles need to be created.

I would like to move this to a more distributed architecture where the tiles are served from s3 and if they don't exist, they get rendered by any number of celery tasks creating tiles and caching them to s3.

My inital thought was to set up ELB for the tile creation side of things and s3 for the tile cache. The issue would be how to check if a tile exists in s3 before sending it to ELB to get rendered.
I tried setting up nginx in front of the ELB with a `try_files` directive to check s3. This did not work, although i was able to proxy tiles in s3.

My question is how is a use case like this usually managed in AWS architecture? A request comes in, a check is made to a storage location, if it doesn't exist it is created and served back.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the likelihood of a requested tile having already been rendered and stored?  It seems like the answer to this has an impact on the viability and efficiency of a solution.

Comment: Depends on the zoom level and spatial location. We are pre-caching low level tiles, so z0-12 are cached and available as static assets. When a request comes in for a higher zoom level the tile creation is kicked off and stored for future use. This way, frequently visited areas would already be cached. The issue i'm running into now is the caching on the single machine bogs everything down and I cannot serve the static tiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on how you have Nginx configured, but it sounds like you need to configure it to always hit a dynamic back-end process that can check if the map tile exists yet. That process would create the tile if it doesn't exist, then return the tile. You can cache the HTTP response so that the process doesn't get bogged down checking if the same tile exists over and over.

If I was starting a project like this from scratch I would probably create a database to store information about each map tile, maybe DynamoDB. That database would contain the records of each created tile. When you get a request, you first do a database lookup to get the S3 location of the tile. If you don't get a database record back you create the tile, upload it to s3, update your database table, and return the tile. You could have lots of these servers running behind a load balancer, adding more as load increases.

I would use Redis (ElastiCache) to store the database query results to speed up subsequent requests for the same tile. I would also place a CDN like CloudFront or CloudFlare in front of the whole thing with caching really cranked up so that subsequent requests for the same tile don't even hit your server.